# Custom NSFetchreqeust - sort parent entities by child NSSet attributes [MagicalRecord+Coredata]

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

This is my project data model. 
[image: Data model]

The data model here is for a simple IM app.
 1. user <-> conversation (1 to 1 at this stage)
 2. conversation <-> message (1 to many)

I call the below code to save message I received from web-socket, which is a JSON string. And I simply phrase them into Coredata entity.

```
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

        ChatMessage* chatMessage = [ChatMessage MR_createInContext:localContext];

        NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"];

        [chatMessage setCreateDate:[formatter dateFromString:[jsonData valueForKey:@"createDate"]]];
        [chatMessage setMessageBody:[jsonData valueForKey:@"textBody"]];
        [chatMessage setMessageID:[jsonData valueForKey:@"id"]];
        [chatMessage setSenderID:[jsonData valueForKey:@"senderID"]];

        if ( ! [[jsonData valueForKey:@"readDate"] isEqualToString:@"NULL"])
            [chatMessage setReadDate:[formatter dateFromString:[jsonData valueForKey:@"readDate"]]];
        else
            [chatMessage setReadDate:nil];


        if ([ChatConversation MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"user.userID" withValue:[jsonData valueForKey:@"senderID"]]) {

            ChatConversation* conversation = [ChatConversation MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"user.userID" withValue:[jsonData valueForKey:@"senderID"] inContext:localContext];

            [conversation addMessageObject:chatMessage];

        }else{
            ChatConversation* conversation = [ChatConversation MR_createInContext:localContext];
            [conversation setConversationID:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",[[ChatConversation MR_numberOfEntities] integerValue] +1]];
            [conversation addMessageObject:chatMessage];
            [conversation setUser:[ChatUser MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"userID" withValue:[jsonData valueForKey:@"senderID"] inContext:localContext]];
        }

} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    [self displayMRRecord];
}];
```

The current challenge is this, I need to create a message inbox tableview. 
like this[image]

The "Conversation" is sorted by the last message "createDate".
So I created a UITableViewController to do that.

And this is my fetchedResultsController init code.

```
    _fetchedResultsController = [ChatConversation MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"message.createDate" ascending:TRUE withPredicate:nil groupBy:nil delegate:self];
```

I realised the problem is,,,

1. message is a NSSet, a set of entities, so message.createDate is not appropriate
2. I need to create a custom NSFetchRequest and init the fetchedResultsController with it

So my real question is,
how to construct a NSFetchRequest that sort parent entities (ChatConversation in this case) by the last object of child entities set attribute (latest message.createDate).

I have googled it for a whole day but can't find any useful resource. 
Does anyone have experience dealing with this kind of problem??
Thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

Hell yeah i have solved it by myself.

```
   _fetchedResultsController = [ChatConversation MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"message.createDate" ascending:TRUE withPredicate:nil groupBy:nil delegate:self];
```

this line is called in wrong manner. 
I should put it in this way.

1. Fetch all the ChatConversation entities to fetchResultsController.fetchedObject array

   ```
   _fetchedResultsController = [ChatConversation MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"conversationID" ascending:TRUE withPredicate:nil groupBy:nil delegate:self];
   ```
2. And then simply sort the fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects array with custom NSSortDescripter

   ```
   NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"message[LAST].createDate" ascending:YES];

   NSArray *sortDescriptors1 = @[sortDescriptor];

   [_fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors1];
   ```